# Expose visibilityChanged event c# from parent control

Tags: c#, events

I would like to expose the visibilityChanged event from an inner control from it's parents interface but I'm doing something wrong. How can I go about this? I need this to be able to attach event handlers in the parent controls parent.

```
public Event InnerControlViewerVibilityChanged {
    get { return this.innerControl != null && this.InnerControl.VisibleChanged; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Parent-Control: declare the event as a member

```
public event EventHandler InnerVisibilityChanged;
```

and attach to the inner event in the ctor:

```
this.InnerControl.VisibleChanged += (o, args) => 
{
    if (this.InnerVisibilityChanged != null)
        this.InnerVisibilityChanged(o, args);
}
```

Comment: In witch ctor do I attatch to the event?

Comment: Never mind I understand now. I added the second part to the ctor in the inner control and voila.